# Unable to create a vector and shuffle it

Tags: random, rust

I'm trying to create a vector with the numbers 48 to 57 and then randomly shuffle it. I'm running into the following errors

```
error: the type of this value must be known in this context
        let &mut slice = secret_num.as_mut_slice();
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: no method named `shuffle` found for type `rand::ThreadRng` in the current scope
        rng.shuffle(&mut slice);
            ^~~~~~~
```

Here's the code:

```
extern crate rand;

fn main() {
    //Main game loop
    loop{
        let mut secret_num = (48..58).collect();
        let &mut slice = secret_num.as_mut_slice();
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        rng.shuffle(&mut slice);                                            
        println!("{:?}", secret_num);
        break;
    }
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `collect` needs to know what type you wish to collect into. From the looks of it, you want a `Vec`:

   ```
   let mut secret_num: Vec<_> = (48..58).collect();
   ```
2. You don't want to use `&mut` in the declaration of this variable because that would make `slice` an unsized type, which isn't valid to have. In fact, this line is redundant.

   ```
   let &mut slice = secret_num.as_mut_slice();
   ```
3. Traits must be brought into scope. The error message you are already getting *should already be telling you this*. Rust has pretty good error messages most of the time. You should read them:

   ```
   help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope;
         the following trait is implemented but not in scope,
         perhaps add a `use` for it:
   help: candidate #1: `use rand::Rng`
   ```
4. There's no need for a `loop` at all; remove it. Produce an [MCVE](/help/mcve) when asking a question to help you understand the source of the problem and others to answer it. In your real program, you should get the random number generator *once* before the loop to avoid overhead.
5. Since you originally asked the question, rand has reorganized their code. `shuffle` is now part of the [`SliceRandom`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.5/rand/seq/trait.SliceRandom.html#tymethod.shuffle) trait.

```
use rand::seq::SliceRandom; // 0.6.5

fn main() {
    let mut secret_num: Vec<_> = (48..58).collect();
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    secret_num.shuffle(&mut rng);

    println!("{:?}", secret_num);
}
```